# Async waterfall equivalent with Q

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, deferred, q

I've got a single page which is an account settings page. In it, I allow my users to update their avatar (if they've attached an image), change their email (if it has been changed from the original), and change their name and password.

Right now, I'm using async's `waterfall` method, but am swapping out async for Q since I prefer the syntax (and api). I'm wondering if this is the way that I should be using Q in replacement of async's waterfall.

I'm doing something like this:

```
exports.settingsAccountPOST = function(req, res) {
  var doesEmailExist = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    User.findByEmail({
      email: req.body.email
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(user);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var updateEmail = function(email) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    User.updateEmail({
      userId : req.session.user.id,
      email : req.body.email
    }, function(err, updated) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(updated);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var updateName = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    if (req.body.name) {
      User.updateName({
        userId: req.session.user.id,
        name: req.body.name
      }, function(err, updated) {
        if (err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
          deferred.resolve(updated);
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };

  doesEmailExist().then(function(email) {
    if (!email) {
      return(updateEmail(email));
    }
  }).then(function() {
    return(updateName())
  }).then(function() {
    res.redirect('/account')
  });
};
```

Say that there is an error with the email address being used. Is there a way to "pass" it to the final call? Use case: Updated password properly, but email update didn't work, so I want to show a session flash to the user telling them they updated their password properly, but there was an issue with updating their email.

I was looking in the docs and it seems I may need to use:

```
.fin(function () {
});
```

Is this correct? If so, what should I be passing into that? Just push to an object the error that occurred within the chain and then loop through all errors and display them to the user? Or just return immediately and display the error?

Comment: Two years later... I am in a similar situation. Async waterfall vs. Q promises. Are you happy with the switch? You liked the syntax and API but is there something else that you found along the way? Since you have apparently used both, given a choice, which one would you prefer now? I am tying to make a decision on which way to go... Async waterfall or Q for sequential execution of async functions.

Comment: They both really do the same thing. Async is a solid library. I've been using bluebird more, recently though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `Q.defer` you are generally doing something wrong.

```
var findByEmail = Q.nbind(User.findByEmail, User);
var updateEmail = Q.nbind(User.updateEmail, User);
var updateName = Q.nbind(User.updateName, User);

//later on...

exports.settingsAccountPOST = function (req, res) {
    findByEmail({
        email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            return updateEmail({
                userId: req.session.user.id,
                email: req.body.email
            });
        }
    })
    .then(function () {
        return updateName({
            userId: req.session.user.id,
            name: req.body.name
        })
    })
    .then(function () {
        res.redirect("/account");
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        //Handle any error
    });
};
```

Comment: Dude, nice. Thanks! Why am I doing something wrong if I use `Q.defer`? I've used denodeify before for db calls, so what's the difference between that, nbind, and this? Reading about them in the repo make me even more confused.

Comment: @BobCobb `denodeify` is an alias for `nbind` - they are the same function. Because `.defer` breaks a promise chain and therefore kills any benefits from using promises. It should be only used to wrap some API that doesn't return promises - but you can use `denodeify` for that. Otoh some rare APIs don't work with `denodeify`, in that case you must use defer.

Comment: Thanks. How can I reject the error (aka throw it) if it doesn't satisfy one of the requirements. I know I can `throw new Error('Error reason')` but it'll still attempt to complete the rest of the methods. I just want it to return from everything.

Comment: @BobCobb if you throw an error it will not attempt to complete the rest of the methods but immediately jump into the catch handler

Comment: @bob_cobb Two years later... I am in a similar situation. Async waterfall vs. Q promises.  Are you happy with the switch? You liked the syntax and API but is there something else that you found along the way?  Since you have apparently used both, given a choice, which one would you prefer now? I am tying to make a decision on which way to go... Async waterfall or Q for sequential execution of async functions.